# Most powerful test and its size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, neyman-pearson-lemma

[image: I]
am getting halfway to the answer but not being able to get the final result in terms of chi square values[image: So i have gone this far.After this i am confused about what to do.Should i take the integral of the likelihood function under H0 Or should i just use the given function instead?]

Comment: Hint: the four choices have four distinct DF parameters (4 down to 1), so all you need to determine is the correct DF.  You can read that directly off the formula for $f$.

Comment: How ?M sorry.M relatively new to this topics and i get lost in small easy things.

Comment: I had figured out that the df would do the trick.But i dont know how to get the df.